# Show Taiwan Map in Android Application

Tags: android, dictionary, android-mapview, country

Here I develop one application which shows Map in Application. I show map in my app and it is working fine, but I show that country which I want to display in Map from application. So how to do it? Is it possible in Android?

Please help me.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Are you using a MapView?

Comment: What are you using? GoogleMaps, OSMDroid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all track you current position through LocationListener/LocationManager:

```
MyLocation myLocation = new MyLocation();
private void locationClick() {
    myLocation.getLocation(this, locationResult);
}
```

And, zoom out your location through code:

```
mapView.getController().setZoom(17);
```

Then you can see the country mentioned.